# INET6_NTOA output is set as null to varchar(39) variable

Tags: mariadb

The following code snippet was working for me in version 10.2.6. But I saw issues in version 10.2.9, where the variable "ip_full_addr" is returning null instead of expected value 2000::

```
DECLARE ip_full_addr varchar(39) DEFAULT "";
SELECT INET6_NTOA(UNHEX('20000000000000000000000000000000')) into ip_full_addr;
SELECT ip_full_addr;
```

Does anyone have any clue on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a genuine bug. I get the expected result in MySQL 5.7.20 (see below), but it returns null in MariaDB 10.2.10. The issue should be reported in the [MariaDB Jira](https://jira.mariadb.org).

```
mysql> DELIMITER ;;
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE p() CONTAINS SQL BEGIN DECLARE ip_full_addr varchar(39) DEFAULT ""; SELECT INET6_NTOA(UNHEX('20000000000000000000000000000000')) into ip_full_addr; SELECT ip_full_addr; END;;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> call p();
+--------------+
| ip_full_addr |
+--------------+
| 2000::       |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying. I reported this on Mariadb issue tracker and they promptly fixed it. Here's the link to the issue: [MDEV-14116](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14116)